# Show or hide decimals

Tags: kotlin

I have a double value, if that number is like this: 123.00 I need to show it as 123 only, without decimal places, but, if the number is like 123.23 or 123.2, I need to show it with the present decimal places: 123.23 or 123.2, as the case may be.

I have tried with decimal format but I couldn't find the right pattern.

It is a better way to do this than a string conversion and operate with substrings and things like that?

Comment: Thanks to all of you, the solution based on a pattern for DecimalFormat is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DecimalFormat is what you're looking for I think:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val df = DecimalFormat("0.##")
    println(df.format(123.0))
    println(df.format(123.3))
    println(df.format(123.32))
    println(df.format(123.327))
}
```

Output:

```
123
123.3
123.32
123.33
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
fun func(x: Double): String  {
    if (x.rem(1).compareTo(0) == 0){
        return x.toInt().toString();
    } else {
        return x.toString();
    }
}

print(func(1.32132)); //Returns 1.32132

print(func(3.00)); //Returns 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `DecimalFormat` with `setMaximumFractionDigits`. Creating an extension function would keep the complexity away from the call-site:

```
fun Double.toStringRounded(fracDigits: Int) = DecimalFormat().apply {
    setMaximumFractionDigits(fracDigits)
}.format(this)
```

Usage:

```
3.14159.toStringRounded(2) // will be "3.14"
```

Comment: This answers a question the OP didn't ask, and makes assumptions about what the user MIGHT want. You're adding complexity for no reason.  For the simple question the OP poses, your answer is significantly more "tedious", and much less readable.  Reading "3.00.format(2)", how is one to know that this is expected to produce "3" rather than "3.00"?  Seeing the '##' as something uniquely interesting, right above where the pattern is used, is valuable information, not something tedious.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I didn't think you were bashing my answer, and wasn't at all bashing your intent to provide more information.  I teach coding as part of my job, and two things I'm always "bashing" my students about is keeping code as readable as possible and not adding unnecessary complexity.  So I was mostly looking out for future readers who might be steered away from those two ideals.  There are certainly cases, like if you needed to make the precision programmable, where something like your solution might be warranted.  It just, IMO, isn't so here.

Comment: how about 'toStringMinimizeDecimalPlaces()' or something like that?  (extension methods ARE COOL, aren't they?!?!)